# Extract text from multiple images to CSV using OCR

Tags: python, image, ocr, screen-scraping, tesseract

I want  to extract texts from thousand of images and put it into a CSV file. Can anyone tell me how to do that? I have images saved on my desktop.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) as get an idea of what is on-topic and what isn't and also take a look on [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)! Thanks :)

Comment: @alexzander Why not start here? https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Command-Line-Usage.html#simplest-invocation-to-ocr-an-image

Comment: excuse me? something wrong to my code?

Comment: @alexzander No, sorry for the misunserstanding, it was the answer to your comment on my comment. OP (member since today) showed absolutely nothing they tried. And that's why I pointed to the rules.

Answer (score 3):

sure.

install pytesseract module using this command:

```
pip install pytesseract
```

install tesseract engine executable from one of these urls:

- [tesseract v5.0.0 cmd 32 bit](https://digi.bib.uni-mannheim.de/tesseract/tesseract-ocr-w32-setup-v5.0.0-alpha.20201127.exe)
- [tesseract v5.0.0 cmd 64 bit](https://digi.bib.uni-mannheim.de/tesseract/tesseract-ocr-w64-setup-v5.0.0-alpha.20201127.exe)
- or [click here to find the latest version](https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki)

create a python script called `images_to_csv.py` and paste this code:

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image # pip install Pillow

# set tesseract cmd to the be the path to your tesseract engine executable 
# (where you installed tesseract from above urls)

# IMPORTANT: this should end with '...\tesseract.exe'
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = <path_to_your_tesseract_cmd>

# and start doing it

# your saved images on desktop
list_with_many_images = [
  "path1",
  "path2"
  # ...
  "pathN"
]

# create a function that returns the text
def image_to_str(path):
    """ return a string from image """
    return pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(path))

# now pure action + csv part
with open("images_content.csv", "w+", encoding="utf-8") as file:
  file.write("ImagePath, ImageText")
  for image_path in list_with_many_images:
    text = image_to_str(image_path)
    line = f"{image_path}, {text}\n"
    file.write(line)
```

this is all for beginning.

if you want to use module `csv` go ahead.

enjoy.